# Equivalency in the elementary measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that:

$f\geqslant0$ and $\int f =0 $ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mu$({$x$$\in$$X:$ $f($x$)>0$})=$0$

My idea:

Let

{$x$$\in$$X:$ $f($x$)>n$}=$E_{n}$

$\mu$({$x$$\in$$X:$ $f($x$)>n$})=$\int\chi_{E_{n}}$=$\frac{1}{n}$$\int(n\chi_{E_{n}})$$\leqslant$$\frac{1}{n}$$\int f$=$\frac{0}{n}$

But here I get $\frac{0}{0}$ for n=0...

Comment: Use what you have done or all $n =1/k$, where $k \in \Bbb{N}$. Finally, countable unions of null sets are null sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leta $A_n =\left\{x\in X :f(x)>\frac{1}{n} \right\} .$ If for some $k$ we have $\mu (A_k ) >0$ then $$\int_X fd\mu \geqslant \int_{A_k}  fd\mu \geqslant \frac{1}{k} \mu (A_k ) >0 .$$
Therefore $\mu (A_k ) =0 $ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and hence $$\mu (\{x\in X :f(x)>0\} ) =\lim_{n\to \infty } \mu (A_n )=0 .$$

Comment: That helped, thanks. But isn't it only this $\Rightarrow$ implication?

Comment: To show $\Leftrightarrow$ we need to consider simple function $h=\sum c_j*\chi_{E_{j}} \leq f$. And this will be correct only for $h=0$. So we get the integral as the supremum of the simple function. And this is 0.